# Can't I just grease the Baking Sheet instead of using Parchment Paper

Tags: baking, parchment

Recipes such as http://paleoleap.com/avocado-banana-chocolate-cookies/ say to line baking sheet with parchment paper. Why can't we just grease the baking sheet?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I bake cookies without baking paper?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/112958/can-i-bake-cookies-without-baking-paper)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Usually you can - our great-grandmothers didn't have parchment paper.

There are a few cases where parchment is preferrable, usually with very, very sticky dough. It saves time when it comes to scrubbing the cookie sheet.

Answer (score 0):

I resisted using parchment for a long time to wanting to start with a single use item. Then, on America’s Test Kitchen (or one of its other franchises), they said they use it until it falls apart. Now, I almost always use it so I don’t have to scrub the cooked grease/oil off my pans.

Comment: Welcome and thanks for your input. If you take the [tour] and browse through the [help], especially [answer], you will notice that this post doesn’t really answer the question - it’s not about how to use parchment, but whether it’s really necessary. I would recommend an [edit] to ensure that your post answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

Besides assisting in easy clean up, parchment paper provides more even cooking and baking and a neater way to make straight cuts in baked goods. For more details, see: https://www.thepioneerwoman.com/food-cooking/cooking-tips-tutorials/a93622/7-reasons-to-use-parchment-paper/