# Using parchment paper to bake whoopie pies

Tags: baking, parchment

My recipe for whoopie pies calls to grease and flour a baking sheet.  Can I simply use parchment paper on the baking sheet instead?

Comment: Related: "reverse" question here: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/51824/cant-i-just-grease-the-baking-sheet-instead-of-using-parchment-paper/51827#51827

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Absolutely**. 
There are only a few cases where parchment and grease/flour are not interchangeable and whoopie pies are not one of them.